# python3 socket server couldn't send FIN/ACK during sock.recv()

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

In this case, socket connection looks bit strange..
Server socket keeps to connect with client socket.
Client socket sends socket close ( FIN )
and then Server socket won't send automatically (FIN/ACK)

The reason is that FIN from client is converted to the message of length 0 by server socket.recv.

So, I revice it. (reference to the No1 in code)

But, in this code, server socket won't send FIN/ACK
although client.close and sock.close are executed.

Here is code

```
class PLC_Server(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ip_address="localhost", port=5000):
        super(PLC_Server, self).__init__()
        self.ip = ip_address
        self.port = port
        self.comm = {"address": self.ip + ":" + str(self.port)}
        self.buffer_size = 4096
        self.client = None

    def _init_socket(self, listen_num=1):
        # ソケットの生成。
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.bind((self.ip, int(self.port)))
        self.sock.listen(listen_num)


    def run(self):
        self._init_socket()
        while True:
            self.client, address = self.sock.accept()
            while True:
                recv_data = self.client.recv(4096)

                if recv_data == b"":
                # No1
                # FIN is convered to lenght 0 message by the sock.recv 
                    print("Detect Client's socket close")
                    self.sock.close()
                    self.client.close()
                    self._init_socket()
                    break
                else:
                    self.client.send("OK")
                    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    th1 = PLC_Server();
    th1.start()
```

Comment: *"But, in this code, server socket won't send FIN/ACK "* - how do you know? Did you make a packet capture to verify this? Please provide it. Also, it makes no sense to close the server socket (listener) and then reopen it - just keep it open, only the connected socket (self.client) should be closed. I've also removed the *multithreaded* tag since there is nothing multithreaded here.

Comment: Yes I use the packet capture to check server socket answer.
The reason why the server socket reopen is that connection must be reconnected right after  client 
 restart.

Comment: *"Yes I use the packet capture to check server socket answer"* - please provide it (as I already asked in the comment).. *"The reason why the server socket reopen is that connection must be reconnected right after client restart."* - there is no need for closing and reopening the server socket in this case, just leave it open and accept the new connection.

Comment: " please provide it" to reproduce it, could you add "sock.recv" on client side after sock.send.

Comment: What has adding `sock.recv` to do with providing the packet capture and also with your FIN/ACK problem  in general?

Comment: You're right, Sending FIN/ACK is not problem.

Comment: But, It is problem that Sock.recv don't send "ACK" before "FIN/ACK" in this script..

Comment: I make new question.
If you're still interested in it, please check it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74106903/python3-socket-server-couldnt-send-ack-of-conn-recv-before-conn-close-is-exec