# python3 socket server couldn't send ACK of conn.recv() before conn.close is executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp

I check the packet of the following code with WireShark.

WireShark tells that conn.recv() don't send ACK after client socket close.

(According to Wireshark, Here is packet after client socket close.

client >> server : FIN/ACK

server >> clinet : FIN/ACK
)

The cause is that conn.close() is executed before conn.recv() sends ACK.
You can check it by uncommenting time.sleep(1).
(According to Wireshark, Here is packet after client socket close on the above condition
client >> server : FIN/ACK

server >> client : ACK

server >> clinet : FIN/ACK
)

Could you tell me how to set socket that surely send conn.recv() ACK before the next code (conn.close) is executed?

```
class PLC_Server:
    def __init__(self, ip_address="localhost", port=5000):
        self.ip = ip_address
        self.port = port
        self.comm = {"address": self.ip + ":" + str(self.port)}
        self.buffer_size = 4096
        self.client = None

    def _init_socket(self, listen_num=1):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.bind((self.ip, int(self.port)))
        self.sock.listen(listen_num)


    def run(self):
        self._init_socket()
        while True:
            conn, address = self.sock.accept()
            while True:
                recv_data = conn.recv(4096)

                if recv_data == b"":
                # FIN is convered to lenght 0 message by the conn.recv 
                    print("Detect Client's socket close")
                    # time.sleep(1)
                    conn.close()
                    break
                else:
                    conn.send("OK")
                    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = PLC_Server()
    test.run()
```

Comment: The peer is not required to send an ACK immediately and also not as a single packet without data. The ACK itself is obviously send - together with FIN. Everything looks fine to me.

Comment: Client requires to ACK before receiving FIN/ACK like the packets of uncommenting time.sleep(1).  Without ACK before receiving FIN/ACK, client send repeatably FIN/ACK of client socket close, because client might think that FIN/ACK from client don't reach to server.

Comment: *"Client requires to ACK before receiving FIN/ACK "* - looks like a broken client to me then. This needs to be fixed in the client, not by changing how TCP operates.

Comment: Why do you think that client is broken?  According to some Web site, it is said that server client send ACK before FIN/ACK. like http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionTermination-2.htm    https://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP-4-times-close.md       So, that's why client requires ACK before FIN/ACK from server

Comment: I cannot find where on this website this is said. Please point be to the specific place which you interpret this way. It might be possible that you are just interpreting it wrong. Apart from that, the ultimate truth about these things is of course not "some Web site" but the actual standard.

Comment: Figure.214 
 in http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionTermination-2.htm says that server sends ACK after receiving FIN from client. So I understand that server sends ACK after receiving FIN from client.

Comment: Figure 214 does not say that the ACKis sent in its own packet, only that the ACK is sent. It might well be combined with other information in the same packet. If the server has still payload to send then the ACK will be combine with the payload. If the server will close the connection too then the ACK will be combined with the FIN in the same packet.